# Two clicks for alert confirmation dialog on JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, click, alert

I have a dialog alert on javafx application. When I click on any of the buttons (yes or not), I have to click for two times for doing the action of each button. I just want one click! Could anybody helps me?

Method for creating alerts:

```
public class AlertMessages {
    public static boolean alertConfirmation(String header, String text) {
        Alert dialog = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        dialog.setHeaderText(header);
        dialog.setContentText(text);
        dialog.setResizable(true);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(350, 200);
        dialog.showAndWait();
        final Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        return result.get() == ButtonType.OK;
    }
}
```

Calling the method:

```
public class OverviewController {
     ...
     ...

     @FXML
     private void handleButton() {
          ...
          else if (...) {
               header = "...";
               text = "...";
               boolean res = AlertMessages.alertConfirmation(header, text);
               if (res) {
                   ...
               } else {
                   ...
               }
          ...
     }

     ...
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `dialog.showAndWait()` twice:

```
dialog.showAndWait();
final Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
```

Just remove the first call.

Comment: :O Unbeliaveble... I copied the creation of the dialog of another one and I forgot to delete the call... That's crazy. Thanks!